# AngularJS - using ng-model inside a directive with repeats and dynamic html controls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a directive for a grid and I want to be able to pass in a column definition that may be an html control with a ng-model and ng-click directive.  I keep getting "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" and the ng-model isn't binding.  I put together a simple plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ue1lQqvrUE0M5zZXsg8a?p=preview as an example.

```js
// Code goes here


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myGridConfig = {};
  $scope.myGridConfig.columnDefs = [{
    field: 'facility',
    headerName: 'Facility'
  }, {
    field: 'code',
    headerName: 'Code'
  }, {
    field: 'cost',
    headerName: 'Cost'
  }, {
    field: 'conditionRating',
    headerName: 'Conditional Rating'
  }, {
    field: 'extent',
    headerName: 'Extent'
  }, {
    field: 'planYear',
    headerName: 'Plan Year',
    cellRenderer: function(row, de) {
      return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.selected" />';
    }
  }];

  $scope.myGridConfig.rowCollection = [{
    facility: "Atlanta",
    code: "C-RD34",
    cost: 540000,
    conditionRating: 52,
    extent: 100,
    planYear: 2014
  }, {
    facility: "Seattle",
    code: "CRDm-4",
    cost: 23000,
    conditionRating: 40,
    extent: 88,
    planYear: 2014
  }, {
    facility: "Austin",
    code: "GR-5",
    cost: 1200000,
    conditionRating: 92,
    extent: 90,
    planYear: 2014
  }];
});

myApp.directive('cellRender', function($compile) {
  var directive = {};
  directive.restrict = 'A';
  directive.scope = {
    cellRender: "="
  }
  directive.replace = true;
  //directive.template = "<div>{{renderThis(cellRender.row, cellRender.def)}}</div>";
  directive.template = "<div>{{renderThis()}}</div>";
  directive.link = function(scope, ele, attrs) {


    scope.renderThis = function() {
      if (scope.cellRender.def.cellRenderer) {
        ele.html(scope.cellRender.def.cellRenderer(scope.cellRender.row, scope.cellRender.def));
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      }
      return scope.cellRender.row[scope.cellRender.def.field];
    };

    /*scope.renderThis = function(r, d) {
   if (d.cellRenderer)
   {
    ele.html(d.cellRenderer(r,d));
    $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
   }
   return r[d.field];
  };*/

  };

  return directive;
});

myApp.directive('grid', function($compile) {
  var directive = {};
  directive.restrict = 'EA';
  directive.scope = {
    gridConfig: "="
  }
  directive.template = "<table style='border: 1px solid black;'>\n" +
    "<thead>\n" +
    "<tr>\n" +
    "<th ng-repeat=\"def in gridConfig.columnDefs\" >{{def.headerName}}</th>\n" +
    "</tr>\n" +
    "</thead>\n" +
    "<tbody>\n" +
    "<tr ng-repeat=\"row in gridConfig.rowCollection\">\n" +
    "<td ng-repeat=\"def in gridConfig.columnDefs\" ><div cell-render=\"{'row': row, 'def' :def}\"></div></td>\n" +
    "</tr>\n" +
    "</tbody>\n" +
    "</table>";

  directive.link = function(scope, ele, attrs) {

    angular.forEach(scope.gridConfig.rowCollection, function(rr) {
      rr.selected = true;
    });


  };
  return directive;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Test dynamic ngModel</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.29/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.29/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div grid="" grid-config="myGridConfig"></div>
    <div>Row 2 selected: {{myGridConfig.rowCollection[1].selected}}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, here's the plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/6boouR50HiCh2BPuHEp1?p=preview

Suggestions are welcome, if there's a better or cleaner way to do this.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myGridConfig = {};
        $scope.myGridConfig.columnDefs = [{field: 'facility', headerName: 'Facility'},
        {field: 'code', headerName: 'Code'},
        {field: 'cost', headerName: 'Cost'},
        {field: 'conditionRating', headerName: 'Conditional Rating'},
        {field: 'extent', headerName: 'Extent'},
        {field: 'planYear', headerName: 'Plan Year', cellTemplate: '<input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"row.selected\" ng-click=\"clickMe()\"></input>'}];

        $scope.myGridConfig.rowCollection = [{
          facility: "Atlanta",
          code: "C-RD34",
          cost: 540000,
          conditionRating: 52,
          extent: 100,
          planYear: 2014
        }, {
          facility: "Seattle",
          code: "CRDm-4",
          cost: 23000,
          conditionRating: 40,
          extent: 88,
          planYear: 2014
        }, {
          facility: "Austin",
          code: "GR-5",
          cost: 1200000,
          conditionRating: 92,
          extent: 90,
          planYear: 2014
        }];
  
  angular.forEach($scope.myGridConfig.rowCollection, function(rr) {
                        rr.selected = true;
                });
});

myApp.directive('customCellTemplate', function($compile, $sce, $parse) {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'A';
        directive.scope = {
                def : "=",
    row: "="    
        };
        directive.replace = true;
        directive.link = function(scope, ele, attrs) {
    ele.html(scope.def.cellTemplate);
    $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
    
    
    scope.clickMe = function() {
     alert(scope.row.cost);
    };
        };

        return directive;
});

myApp.directive('grid', function($compile, $sce, $parse) {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'EA';
  directive.replace=true;
        directive.scope = {
                gridConfig : "="
        }
        directive.template = "<table style='border: 2px solid black;'>\n" +
                "<thead>\n" +
                        "<tr>\n" +
                                "<th ng-repeat=\"def in gridConfig.columnDefs\" >{{def.headerName}}</th>\n" +
                        "</tr>\n" +
                "</thead>\n" +
                "<tbody>\n" +
                        "<tr ng-repeat=\"row in gridConfig.rowCollection\">\n" +
                                "<td ng-repeat=\"def in gridConfig.columnDefs\" >\n" +
         "<div custom-cell-template=\"\" ng-if=\"def['cellTemplate']\" row=\"row\" def=\"def\"></div><div ng-if=\"!def['cellTemplate']\">{{row[def.field]}}</div>\n" +
        "</div></td>\n" +
                        "</tr>\n" +
                "</tbody>\n" +
        "</table>";
        return directive;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Angular-scrollable-table directive demo</title>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.29/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.29/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div grid="" grid-config="myGridConfig"></div>
          2{{myGridConfig.rowCollection[1].selected}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```